# Localization in .NET

Tags: asp.net, localization

Hi I am using Resoursce files as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

I am setting the culture info programatically as opposed to at the top in the page declaration.  Do I need to declare the culture info for each page?  Is there something I can do to change the culture info for all pages using one line?  I am using a master page.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the culture to be set to the browser's settings, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744673/localization-in-net/744689#744689). If you need to set the culture to something programmatically, use the following:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        base.InitializeCulture();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ...;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ...;
    }
}
```

Then make sure all of your pages inherit from MyPage instead of Page.

Answer (score 1):

Set the culture in the code behind for the master page, or on a base class that all of your pages descend from.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default culture in web.config by adding through the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element.